# Extract text from img's thumb "alt" or "title" attribute and use it as a signature for enlarged popup photo

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails, signature

Is it possible to do so?
Example: I get image **img src="some_img_thumb.png" alt="That's the image alt" title="That's the image title"** which is thumbnail and has both **alt** and **title** attributes. When i hover mouse over it or click on it, enlarged image should pop up. Now, i want make this image pop up with it's **alt** or **title** as a *signature*, placed on bottom img's border. I know some other trick ( http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-popup-image-viewer ), but i'd like to know if this what i want achieve is possible. I'm sure it's related with this statement:

**a:after
{
content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}**

but the way i tried to use **content: attr(title);** statement, was bad way:

**img.thumb:active img.thumb:after
{
   content: attr(title);
   font-weight: bold;
   margin: 10px 400px 20px 400px;
}**

I'm newbie into webdesign and was searching for inspiration to achieve that trick, but still no ideas.

Thanks for eventual help. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably want to use jquery for that one. You can harvest the alt tag, or any other attribute with the following line

```
var altText = $('img').attr('alt');
```

You'd probably want to use an id on the image as well to make sure you get the right one.

Then you can the value to the signature with the following line.

```
$('#signature').append(altText);
```

If you'd like more specific directions comment and I'll be happy to help you further.

That's the theory, but there are some great lightbox plugins out there that have this functionality. Have you tried colorbox?

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Comment: Yes, you could post some more specific comments, if you want to, so i'll try use them to find solution. Thanks

Comment: Honestly, you're describing what many plugins do. Did you check out colorbox?

Comment: Oh, forgot about it. Sorry :P I'll check it, but i think i could achieve what i want with help of <div> . When i get solution, i'll post it here. Cheers

Comment: I've just migrated to WordPress and used Fancybox plugin for WordPress theme. Easy :P